# Are docker images bound to a specific operating system?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, unix, operating-system

I am fairly new to DOCKER and as far as I know that it should enable to port software independent of the target operating system. However I have come across some projects that use "run_docker.sh" files which then have commands like these: [Whole script here](https://github.com/Xilinx/Vitis-AI/blob/master/docker_run.sh)

```
docker run \
    $docker_devices \
    -v /opt/xilinx/dsa:/opt/xilinx/dsa \
    -v /opt/xilinx/overlaybins:/opt/xilinx/overlaybins \
    -e USER=$user -e UID=$uid -e GID=$gid \
    -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm \
    -v $HERE:/workspace \
    -w /workspace \
    -it \
    --rm \
    --network=host \
    $IMAGE_NAME \
    bash
```

Clearly /opt/ and /dev/ are unix specific folders - is it possible to port them to Windows? Is this a 'bad' use case of Docker? Is it possible to execute the docker run command with some changes on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes and no.

We have to be a bit specific here:

1. Docker as a software is installable on a lot of OS, e.g. For windows: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/
2. When installed Docker itself will operate within it's own OS, so you can switch between an Unix and Windows mode. https://forums.docker.com/t/cli-to-switch-between-linux-and-windows-images/30297

   So every image will be loaded within a a linux or windows and so are the structures (e.g. file / folder structure)

   When the image is loaded you can have a lot of OS running within the docker container, e.g. windows in every version you wish and a nearly unlimited amount of Linux OS, e.g. Ubuntu: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu

Comment: so in order to get this script to run I should create a docker image that uses a UNIX system and then start the docker file in this system (so a docker container inside a docker container) - cause when I run the command_run.sh it will fail because of non found folders like /dev/

Comment: Well, yes and no.
You try to bind a volumne with -v FROM /dev/shm  TO /dev/shm
Means the docker command awaits a Unix-Like file system WITHIN the docker AND a Unix-like file system WITHIN the container.
If you using docker for windows it might make problems even IF you fix everything, its a known issue.
Look into changing your volumes (-v propertys) to named volumnes (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) Named volumnes are managed by the docker software itself and you dont have to care about at least one side